# Angular7 Subscriber is not a function

Tags: angular, promise, observable, subscriber

```
//myService.ts
//customhttpservice is just an observable returning http request response.



public getCPData(): Observable<any> {

    if (localStorage.getItem('resind')) {
     return of(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resind')));
    } else {

      return this.customHttpService.get(url, headers, params, '')
      .toPromise()
      .then(resp => {
        localStorage.setItem('resind', resp)
        return resp;
       },
       error => console.error(error)
      );
    }
   }

//myComponent.ts


this.myService.getCPData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
    });
```

for the above code when i try to subscirbe to myservice i am receiving subscriber is not a function error. Can someone help me what is wrong here.

Comment: you are mixing promises and observables, so that won't work. You can't subscribe to a promise

Comment: can you tell me how can i acheive this only with subscribing and observables. I know we shouldn't subscribe inside a service to avoid memory leakage, so i used promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subscribe to promises, instead return an observable:

```ts
 import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

 // ...

 return this.customHttpService.get(url, headers, params, '').pipe(
   tap(resp => localStorage.setItem('resind', resp))
   catchError( /** do stuff **/)
 )
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear :)